# Populate selected items in multi select list from URL

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have a list that allows multiple selections to be made and then submitted. What I now need to do is populate the select box so that the values submitted remain in the following page.

I'm passing the variable in the url and can list them using the following:

```
    foreach ($_GET['sector'] as $selectedOption)
```

My thinking is to store the results in an array and then when the list is created loop through with the following:

```
    if (in_array($optionvalue, $selectedOption))
    {
    echo "<option value='".$optionvalue."' selected='selected>".$optionvalue."</option>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<option value='".$optionvalue."'>".$optionvalue."</option>";
    }
```

The above works but only for whatever the last selected item is.

Is this the correct way to do this or is there a simpler method?

Comment: maybe you could try something like instead of the if -> `echo '<option value="'.$optionvalue.'" '.( (in_array($optionvalue, $selectedOption)) ? 'selected' : '' ).'>'.$optionvalue.'</option>';`

Comment: Thank you for this - however i'm thinking my array might now be the problem.  It doesn't seem to contain all of the url data.